# How can you make a hip holster for minifigs?

Tags: building, minifigures

Is there a way to create a holster of some sort so you could attach a LEGO pistol to the side of a minifig, around the hips?

Comment: You could use a piece of coloured paper and some glue/tape to make one to wedge between the torso and legs, similar to [these](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50581&name=Minifigure,%20Skirt%20Cloth%206%20Large%20Points%20(Grass)&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Body%20Wear%5D#T=C&C=36) kind of skirts.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's kinda chunky, but the best I can come up with is [42446](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42446&idColor=88) + [2555](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2555&idColor=88):

[image] + [image] =

[image]

It would leave a half-plate gap on one side if they only have 1 holster though, but at-least you keep the regular minifig legs.

**NOTE:** This probably wouldn't be considered a "legal" connection, due to the semi-octagonal shape of the leg connectors. It's definitely possible to put these pieces together, but it puts a bit of strain on the ring of the thin piece.

[image]

Comment: Just call the gap "the belt buckle."

Comment: Wow looks fantastic, but the neck holes might be too small to fit onto the minifigure leg studs (which are square-ish).

Comment: @Pubby Great question! I had to build it in real life to check on this. It kinda fits, but puts a bit of strain on the piece.

Answer (score 23):

Three 1x1 plates, two 1x1 round bricks, and one 1x1 plate with clip.

[image]

Comment: It's also possible to do this with regular legs, even if it's not strictly "legal" - there will be an unsightly gap between the legs and holster.